# Eclipse PDE build fails to find jar location on customAssembly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm running a PDE build - pretty much defaults ( see at the end of the message ) which manages to copy all my plugins/features, resolve them, compile them and generate p2 metadata.

At the `customAssembly` step it fails misteriously with

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/scripts    /build.xml:38: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/scripts   /build.xml:129: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/templates/headless-build/customTargets.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/templates/headless-build/allElements.xml:16: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/scripts/genericTargets.xml:192: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/eclipse.build/package.com.itsolut.mantis_feature.all.xml:23: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/eclipse.build/package.com.itsolut.mantis_feature.all.xml:15: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/robert/apps/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.0.v20090527-1800/templates/headless-build/allElements.xml:31: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/eclipse.build/package.com.itsolut.mantis_feature.xml:99: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/eclipse.build/package.com.itsolut.mantis_feature.xml:169: /tmp/eclipse.build/tmp/eclipse/plugins/javax.xml.soap_1.3.0.v200904281458 not found.
```

Strangely enough, there is a jar file located in the /tmp/eclipse.build/tmp/eclipse/plugins/ directory:

```
/tmp/eclipse.build/tmp/eclipse/plugins/javax.xml.soap_1.3.0.v200904281458.jar
```

I'm out of idea since this is supposed to be a completely automatic process, but yet it fails misteriously.

Any ideas?

---

### Build file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Build Mylyn-Mantis" default="runBuild">

<property name="builder" location="."/>
<property name="topLevelElementId" value="com.itsolut.mantis_feature"/>
<property name="baseLocation" location="${eclipse.home}"/>
<property name="base" location="${baseLocation}/.."/>
<property name="buildDirectory" location="${java.io.tmpdir}/eclipse.build"/>

<import file="${eclipse.pdebuild.scripts}/build.xml"/>

<target name="copyProjects">
    <delete dir="${buildDirectory}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}"/>

    <record name="${buildDirectory}/${topLevelElementId}-build.log" loglevel="verbose"/>

    <echoproperties/>

    <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/features/${topLevelElementId}"/>
    <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/features/${topLevelElementId}">
        <fileset dir="../com.itsolut.mantis-feature"/>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins"/>

    <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/plugins">
        <fileset dir="..">
            <include name="com.itsolut.mantis/**"/>
            <include name="com.itsolut.mantis.core/**"/>
            <include name="com.itsolut.mantis.ui/**"/>
            <exclude name="*/bin/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="runBuild" depends="copyProjects,main"/>
```

### Complete source

Brave souls can take a look at [the project in svn](http://mylyn-mantis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mylyn-mantis/trunk/com.itsolut.mantis.pde/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are hitting [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=265471).

As a workaround, try adding `unpack="false"` attributes to your com.itsolut.mantis_feature/feature.xml for the binary jar'ed plugins you are including (ie probably most of the javax.* bundles).